# Difference and usage on "teléfono" and "telefónica"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

Es "número de teléfono" pero "tarjeta telefónica". ¿Cómo puedo decidir qué forma es (más) *correcta*?

---

It's "Número de **teléfono**", but "Tarjeta **telefónica**". How can I tell which word is more appropriate. What actually is the difference between these words?
When searching the Internet, I only find much more examples, but no explanation when to use which one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Teléfono* is a noun. *Telefónico* is its corresponding adjective. Since *tarjeta* is feminine, you say *tarjeta telefónica* for *telephone card*.

*Número de teléfono*, on the other hand, means just telephone number. But *numero telefónico* is perfectly acceptable. So both are correct, if that was your question. Maybe the last option sounds slightly more formal. Anyway, when the context is clear you don't even need both words:

> ¿Puedo tener tu número?

or

> ¿Me das tu teléfono?

are both asking for a phone number.
In the last sentence, it's obvious that your interlocutor won't give you the phone itself, but his/her number.

Comment: I guess if my dictionary provides "el telefónico" this is a substantive derived from the adjective?

Comment: @Em1 whose word translation is "el telefónico"? It could be "el (número) telefónico" as in this conversation: "– ¿Me das tu número? –¿Cuál? –El telefónico." But it could be also the *bill*: "– ¿Ya pagaste el recibo? –¿Cuál? –El telefónico."